# Cannot open 8080 port on EC2

Tags: ubuntu, port-forwarding, iptables, telnet

I use AWS Ubuntu Instance and try to open port 8080. This is my "Security Groups" settings:

[ec2 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfjGM.png)

I have added port 8080 to iptables:

```
sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http-alt

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Firewall is disabled:

```
sudo ufw status verbose
Status: inactive
```

nmap:

```
nmap localhost

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-05-04 20:27 UTC
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00012s latency).
Not shown: 998 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
8080/tcp open  http-proxy
```

Netstat:

```
netstat -anltp | grep "LISTEN" 
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2446/node           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

But port still seems to be closed when I use server IP:

```
nmap ec2-18-184-30-11.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-05-04 20:29 UTC
Nmap scan report for ec2-18-184-30-11.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com (172.31.39.14)
Host is up (0.00013s latency).
rDNS record for 172.31.39.14: ip-172-31-39-14.eu-central-1.compute.internal
Not shown: 999 closed ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh
```

What should I do to open port 8080?

Comment: looks like 8080 is bound to 127.0.0.1, so it will not accept traffic except from the local host  (see your netstat local address on the 8080 line). Look at the service you have running on 8080, and configure it to Bind to 0.0.0.0 so that its accessible from anywhere, or the LAN IP address if you want it accessible only to hosts on the LAN. What service do you have running on the port?

Comment: I changed config to 0.0.0.0 and it works!!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the netstat output:

```
netstat -anltp | grep "LISTEN" 
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2446/node           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

The service will only respond to requests from the localhost (127.0.0.1). Changing this to an address on the host that is accessible from the caller's network (or 0.0.0.0 for public access) will make the service accessible. This change is generally made in the service configuration document or interface.